# in this code error is showing "Type or namespace definantion,end of file expected"

Tags: asp.net

Type or namespace definantion,end of file expected

```
public partial class contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text == "")
        {
            /* Label2.Text = "name is compulasry";*/
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('name is compulasry');", true);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SYSTEM2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=amresh;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd;
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Deatil values('"+ TextBox1.Text +"')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
            con.Close();
        }

        void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                    ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;

                ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to close `Button1_Click1`. You're missing a `}`

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text == "")
    {
        /* Label2.Text = "name is compulasry";*/
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('name is compulasry');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SYSTEM2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=amresh;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Deatil values('"+ TextBox1.Text +"')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
        con.Close();
    }
} // <-- This is missed
```

And you need to remove an extra `}` at the end

```
void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
{
     foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
            ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
                ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
    }
}
} // <-- Remove this
```